# Need help understanding this row-by-row file processor

Tags: perl

I am trying to use a downloaded Perl code, which includes the following part used for reading input file row-by-row.

However, I do not quite understand how it works

1. What does `$row[-1]` represent?  Can a row can be indexed from `-1`?
2. How does  `$result{$id}{$group[0]}=$group[1];` work? Is it building a two-dimensional array for result?
3. What does `$df{$group[0]}++;` do? Is that the same as `++` in C++?

```
my $result =();
my $df = ();

while (<FILE>)
{    
   my @row = split;
   my $id = $row[-1];
   for my $i(0 .. $#row - 2)
   {
      my @group = split(/\:/, $row[$i]);
      $result{$id}{$group[0]}=$group[1];
      $df{$group[0]}++;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Your downloaded code was written by someone that does not know Perl very well. Attempting to assign an empty list to a scalar is plain silly. Colons are not meta in regexes and do not need escaping.

Comment: @tadmc : At least they have lexically-scoped their variables :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a run-down of how that code works.

- Define `$result` and `$df`. And for some odd reason, try to assign an empty list to them, even though it doesn't do anything.

  ```
  my $result =();
  my $df = ();
  ```
- Read a line from `FILE` file-handle, and put it into `$_`, for every line.

  ```
  while (<FILE>)
  {
  ```
- Split `$_` on white-space, removing first element if it would be blank.

  ```
    my @row = split;
  ```
- Set `$id` to the last element of `@row`.

  ```
    my $id = $row[-1];
  ```
- Loop on all indexes of `@row` except last two, and set `$i` to the index. This would have been easier to write if the previous operation had been to [`pop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pop.html) the last element of the end. I think it should have been `$#row-1` instead.

  ```
    for my $i(0 .. $#row - 2)
    {
  ```
- Split element of `@row` at location `$i`, by `:`.

  ```
      my @group = split(/\:/, $row[$i]);
  ```
- Index into `%result` (not `$result`).

  First by `$id`, then by first element of `@group`. Setting it to the second value of `@group`.

  ```
      $result{$id}{$group[0]}=$group[1];
  ```
- Increment element of `%df` (not `$df`), by the first value of `@group`. It ends up setting it to `1` if it didn't previously exist.

  ```
      $df{$group[0]}++;
  ```
- End of `for` then `while` loops.

  ```
    }
  }
  ```

---

This is how I would have written it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $filename = 'filename';
open my $fh, '<', $filename;

my %result;
my %df;

while (<$fh>){
  my @row = split;
  my $id = pop @row;
  pop @row; # I assume this should be removed.
  for my $pair (@row){
    my($key,$value) = split(':', $pair);
    $result{$id}{$key} = $value;
    $df{$key}++;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that the `\ ` in `/\:/` is superfluous

Comment: @Zaid If I edit this post again, I will add a note about that. It isn't really a problem though, because they both work.

Comment: You have my +1 though. Great walkthrough.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes code is best explained through an example.

Given a file that contains the following row:

```
AA:BB CC:DD     CC:DD UNIMPORTANT_COL ID
```

The `%result` hash will look like :

```
(
    ID => {
            AA => 'BB',
            CC => 'DD',
          },
)
```

The `%df` hash is counting the number of unique instances:

```
(
    AA => 1,
    CC => 2,
)
```

---

**Side Comments**

- `$#row` is the last index of `@row`, which is 4 in the example above. This means that `$row[$#row]` could have been used instead of `$row[-1]`
- It would be clearer to write `my ( $key, $value ) = split /:/, $group;` and use them instead of `$group[0]` and `$group[1]`
- The `$i` variable is not very useful here. Consider using `foreach my $group ( @group[0..$#group-2]) {` instead

Comment: If `my $id = $row[-1];` had been replaced with `my $id = pop @row;pop @row;` then it could be `for my $group (@group){ ... }`

Answer (score 1):

1. `$row[-1]` represents the last element of `@row` array (`$row[-2]` would represent the one before that and so on)
2. `$result{$id}{$group[0]}=$group[1]` uses bunch of perl short-cuts, actually it is the same as   `$result->{$id}->{$group[0]} = $group[1]`.

   Which means the following:

   - treat `$result` as the reference to a HASH, find an element in that HASH that is associated with the key `$id`, if there is no such elements, create new one
   - treat that element as a reference to a HASH, find an element in that HASH that is associated with the key `$group[0]`, if there is no such elements, create new one
   - assign the value of `$group[1]` to that element

   So `$result` is reference to the HASH of HASHes. (see more about it in [Perl Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#Generation-of-a-HASH-OF-HASHES))
3. `$df{$group[0]}++;` increments value of a key `$group[0]` in HASH referenced by `$df`. The difference with C++ is that when there is no value associated with the key, the value is treated as `0`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Apparently the id is the last column in the row, `$row[-1]` returns the last element in the `@row` array.
2. `$result{$id}{$group[0]}=$group[1]` builds a 2 dimensional HASH by assigning the value `$group[1]` to the combination of keys `$id` and `$group[0]`
3. the increment operator (++) works identically as in C++

Comment: Perl's post-increment (`++`) doesn't always work the same as C++. This command `perl -e'$a=q[a];print$a++ for 1..3'` prints `abc` for example.

Comment: Also use `1.` instead of `1)` to make a list in Markdown. With over 16k rep you should know this by now.